# No margin, full width two colmns view HTML

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to make this https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixSom.jpg

I starterd using bootstrap but there are margins which I don't know to change without destroying it. 
Here is a code

```
<div class="partner views">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 partner-text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis euismod vitae erat eget consequat. Integer id suscipit lacus, a aliquet ipsum.
Integer interdum auctorlorem eu imperdiet. Vivamus et sem eros. Pellentesque sed turpis eu nisi suscipit rutrum non quis erat. Sed risus massa. Vivamus et sem eros. Pellentesque sed turpis eu nisi suscipit rutrum non quis erat. Sed risus massa.
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 partner-image">
     <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/01/06/23/21/soap-bubble-1959327_1280.jpg" alt="">                      
    </div>
    </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 partner-image">
     <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/01/06/23/21/soap-bubble-1959327_1280.jpg" alt="">                      
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 partner-text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis euismod vitae erat eget consequat. Integer id suscipit lacus, a aliquet ipsum.
Integer interdum auctorlorem eu imperdiet. Vivamus et sem eros. Pellentesque sed turpis eu nisi suscipit rutrum non quis erat. Sed risus massa. Vivamus et sem eros. Pellentesque sed turpis eu nisi suscipit rutrum non quis erat. Sed risus massa.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have no idea what to search for. I am a beginner, tried to search for galleries but that is  not it.

Comment: you are missing the **container** element

Comment: also try to put a complete code with HTML/CSS so we can reproduce the issue

Comment: Just override those margins in your  css because those margins come from bootstrap library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
partner-text{
  padding:0px; 
  margin:0px
}
```

Answer (score 1):

as Temani Afif mentioned looks like you are missing [`.container` element](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/).
Also you can try using spacing utils from bootstrap i.e. `mt-0`, `pt-0`. You can find documentation [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/). These utils are present in various versions of Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply add

`body {
   margin: 0px;
}`

to your css (or in the head)